# Unit of weight and mass

Tags: forces, mass, terminology, conventions, weight

Doctor asked me how much did I weigh. 
Should I say it is "*50 kg*" or "*500 N*" ? Though the unit of weight is **Newton**, I have seen people mentioning their weight only in terms of **Kilogram**. Why is it so?

Comment: If you say 50N, doctor will fall from heaven and might not understand anything. It's actually 50kgf.

Comment: Or divide it by g and say: "50/g" kg.

Comment: No, my actual question is how does a weighing machine calculate our weight. We call it as weighing machine( i.e a machine which calculates weight) but it shows the output in terms of "kg" which is the unit of mass, shouldn't it be in terms of Newton or Kgf ?

Comment: @Vivekkarunakaran the measure of mass tells us the amount of matter contained in something (like the no.of fundamental particles it is made up of), it is a scalar quantity i.e. it does represent any direction, it only have a magnitude, whereas weight is the measure of gravitational force acting on the mass or amount of matter (no.fundamental particles) of that body.

Comment: when you say a body weights 8kg you actually meant to say it weights 8kgf - (kilogram force), which is actually not a perfect measure of its weight. In order to calculate your weight, you need to multiply it by the acceleration produced due to gravity, 9.8m/s^2 or approx 10 m/s^2

Comment: Remember - Newton's Second Law? F=ma, where F is the force, m is the mass and a is the acceleration. Since, weight is the measure of a force, we calculate it by multiplying it with mass and acceleration (in this case acceleration caused due to gravity)

Comment: @ajinkyaNaik So do u mean that the machines we use in hospitals only show our mass

Comment: yep, thats right, it is better to represent weight by kgf rather than by only kg to avoid this confusion